# text_field com where para busca em rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, query

Estou começando a estudar rails e estou tentando buscar por nome e data em uma lista.

Gostaria de apresentar na tela dentro da página show essa busca por nome e data

aonde estou tentando criar o formulario na view

```
<form>
<%= text_field(@fees_by_name , "") %>
<%= select_date(@my_date, start_year: Date.today.year - 100, end_year: Date.today.year + 5, order: [:month, :year]) %>
<%= button_to 'Search' %>
</form>
```

def no Controller pra pegar as variaveis globais

```
def show
@my_date = params[:date].nil? ? Date.today : DateTime.new(params[:date][:year].to_i, params[:date][:month].to_i)
@fees = @condominium.fees
end
```